# Confirm dialog doesn't work properly with link element using ui-sref

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Situation:**

I am working on an Angular application where in one page `manageProviders.html` I wanted to add a button to go back to another page `providers.html` which contains the list of all providers.

I used an `<a>` element with a `ui-sref="providers"` attribute, because I use angular states in my application, everything works perfectly.

**Problem:**

But when I tried to add a confirmation dialog with that button so the user confirms his action, actually it show the confirm dialog but doesn't do anything whether I press <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> it doesn't work and the link is always active and keeps forwarding me to the `Providers.html` page.

This is the HTML code of the link with the confirmation code I tried:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" ui-sref="providers">Back</a>
```

---

I even tried it with the following code in my controller and deleted the inline `onclick` event in my link:

```
$('#goBack').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
     e.preventDefault();
  } else {
     $('#goBack').attr("ui-sref", "fournisseur");
  }
});
```

Where `goBack` is the `id` of my `<a>` element, but both solutions doesn't work.

---

This is how I am declaring my states in my application if it helps:

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
  access: {
    requiredLogin: false
  }
}).state('addProvider', {
  url: APPLICATION_URL + '/addProvider',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/content/manageProviders.html',
  parent: 'main',
  controller: 'providerController'
}).state('providers', {
  url: APPLICATION_URL + '/provider',
  templateUrl:   'app/views/content/providers.html',
  parent: 'main',
  controller: 'providerController'
});
```

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is related to the `ui-sref` attribute, because with a simple `href` and the same confirmation code it works perfectly, like you can see in this fiddle:

```html
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="www.google.com">Back</a>
```

How can I achieve it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try use `ng-click` instead `onclick`

Comment: @ThanhTùng It gives the same thing.

Comment: I try make a answer . Hope it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `ui-sref` attribute, that couldn't be assigned dynamically in the `controller` in my previous code and for some reasons was always called if it's used in inline `HTML`.

**Solution:**

So I found a solution by removing it from my `HTML` and using `$location.path` in my `controller` instead.

This is the `controller` code updated:

```
$('#goBack').on('click', function (e) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        $location.path(APPLICATION_URL + '/providers');
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

And everything works perfectly.

**Edit:**

I edited my code to use [@vohidjon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971033/vohidjon-karimjonov)'s suggestion with my existing code and used `$state.go()`, it seems to be the best solution:

```
$('#goBack').on('click', function (e) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }else{
        $state.go('providers');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add directive in a like this

```
<a ng-click="..()"click></a>
```

And in js

```
module.directive('click', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).click(function(event) {
if(//){
            event.preventDefault();
}else{
//
}
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but I think it's not a good idea to create a whole directive just for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-click` to call controller function

```
<a ng-click="goBack()">Go back</a>
```

and in controller, conditionally change `ui-router`'s  `$state`

```
$scope.goBack = function(){
      if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
           $state.go('providers');
      }
}
```

Do not forget to inject `$state` service to your controller

Comment: Nice approach, using the `$state.go()`, it works perfectly.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it helped to solve the issue?

Comment: While your answer gave a good suggestion for using `$state.go()` but it doesn't answer my question about `ui-sref`, and you suggested to use `ng-click` and bind a function to it in controller but I was already doing it.